# iOS Swift PayPal integration. How can I pay customers?

Tags: ios, swift, paypal

For my application, I need to be able to charge customers, as well as pay customers? I was trying it on Stripe but they don't have a good system set up for it. Does anybody know if this is do able with PayPal?

Comment: i think your app will not pass review with paypal payment, you should use apple payments

Comment: Apply payments won't let me do this and it is not something you would do with In App Purchases